Missing Detailed Output in ethtool -T Command on Nvidia Jetson Orin AGX Dev Kit
I am currently using the Nvidia Jetson Orin AGX dev kit with a Basler GigE interface card and two GigE Cameras connected to port 0 and 1 (eth0 and eth1)
I am trying to setup PTP with ptp4l and phc2sys and I'm facing some issues.
When I run ethtool -T eth0 I get the following output:
Time stamping parameters for eth0:
Capabilities:
    hardware-transmit
    software-transmit
    hardware-receive
    software-receive
    software-system-clock
    hardware-raw-clock
PTP Hardware Clock: 0
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes:
    off
    on
Hardware Receive Filter Modes:
    none
    all

I'm getting the same output for eth1. I was expecting to also get some additional info from the above command in () which I am not seeing here.
Can anyone tell me why am I not getting this information? Is there something missing from the system?
as a reference, I was expecting an output of ethtool -T, similar to the example below (note the info inside the parentheses).
> > Capabilities:
> >     hardware-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE)
> >     software-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE)
> >     hardware-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE)
> >     software-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE)
> >     software-system-clock (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE)
> >     hardware-raw-clock    (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE)
> > PTP Hardware Clock: 0
> > Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes:
> >     off                   (HWTSTAMP_TX_OFF)
> >     on                    (HWTSTAMP_TX_ON)

Thanks!
